# Font does not load correclty in electron app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, electron

I am using this font: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=JetBrains Mono' for my electron app using react and when i load it up the electron app does not show the correct font, when i run it through localhost and open it in my browser its closer to the correct font but still not it. Here is a picture that shows the diffrences between the browser, figma and electron app going in that order.

[image: This is the iamge:]

I tried to disable electron web security because sometimes it can cause a problem with font rendering but that wasnt the problem, havent tried anything so far because i am new to electron

this is my index.css file

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
  color: #A5D7E8;
  background-color: #0B2447;
}
```

and this is the head tag my index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Electron</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=JetBrains Mono' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
    />
</head>
```

Comment: It's an electron app, so it's just a browser with all the browser conveniencens, just hidden by default. [Turn on the dev tools](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-debugging) and just look at what's going wrong the same way you would in a browser.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" />` This meta tag is preventing it. If you remove it then you will notice it works.

Comment: i commented it out and it works now thank you very much.